# Edit WorkItem Does Not Work - UI not updated - VS2019 ADOS 2020

Tags: visual-studio-2019, tfs-workitem, azure-devops-server-2020

i am trying to edit work item - using the [Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte)
The UI i see in the preview does not match the Actual UI and removing controls from the UI only update the preview look and the XML but not the server view .

Editing is only updating the preview and the XML but after uploading to the server no change in the UI.

```
MODIFIED XML
```

[MODIFIED XML](https://pastebin.com/xqU8XdXY)

```
ORG XML
```

[ORG XML](https://pastebin.com/th3XCAww)

**Actual Look**
[image]

**Preview Look**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only updating the `layout` section of the work item. That section is deprecated and only exists for legacy purposes; it was used in old versions of TFS for rendering work items, and for rendering work items in Visual Studio. Since modern versions of Visual Studio no longer render work items natively and simply redirect to the web UI, you need to ensure that the `WebLayout` section is updated; that is the section used for rendering work items. This is all spelled out in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops).

You should consider moving off of the "classic" XML work item customization experience to the modern inheritance model; it's much easier to use and doesn't require messing around with XML documents.

Comment: i cant move to inheritance model without losing al the links in our documention,is  there a ui tool that support weblayout?

Comment: @galsi I don't know what your first statement means. You can update your documentation. As for the second, yes -- a web browser is a UI tool. Work item management directly in Visual Studio has been deprecated for years.

Comment: we hvae over 25000 work item which are accessed directly by there WIT ID. after consulting i understand i cannot move from current XML model to inheritance without changing the ID's which is unacceptable by other division of the company .

Comment: @galsi I've never heard of work item IDs changing when moving from XML to inheritance process templates. Can you share the documentation where you found that?

Comment: the process is doing a clone of the Original Process to let you test it before , creating of the cloned WIT give each WIT new ID - trying to clone to a new server in order to keep/set the same ID's failed - also consulted with an expert which replied that clone and keep the same id's cannot be done